# What's wrong with this code-let to compute all subsets?

Tags: python, recursion, set

I am trying to write a recursive function to compute the power set of a given set. This code should print out all subsets of the input set:

```
def ss_r(s):
    # Base
    if len(s) == 0:
        return [set([])]
    # Recursive
    e = s.pop()
    ssl = ss_r(s)
    n = len(ssl)
    for i in range(n):
        ssl.append(ssl[i].copy().add(e))
    return ssl
```

However, when I run this code, I get a traceback with an issue about calling functions on None. What's wrong with this code? It seems, conceptually, to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While conceptually you're trying to do the right thing, one of these lines of code doesn't do what you think it does. Specifically, look here:

```
for i in range(n):
    ssl.append(ssl[i].copy().add(e))    # <--- This line
```

Your logic here - take the old set, copy it, and add in the element `e` - is correct. The problem here is that the `.add` function just adds the element to the set and doesn't return the modified set. As a result, the value of the expression `ssl[i].copy().add(e)` is `None`, hence the error.

To fix this, break this apart into multiple statements:

```
for i in range(n):
    modifiedSet = ssl[i].copy()
    modifiedSet.add(e)
    ssl.append(modifiedSet)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks this solved it, I wonder if there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if there is a more elegant way of doing this.

I agree with @templatetypedef's assessment (+1) of your problem.  I would use slightly different syntax to make the code easier to follow:

```
def ss_r(s):
    # Base case
    if not s:
        return [set()]

    # Recursive
    e = s.pop()
    ssl = ss_r(s)

    for i in range(len(ssl)):
            ssl.append(ssl[i].union({e}))

    return ssl
```